# Desktop is restarting on any popup or tooltip

Tags: unity, compiz, .desktop

I updated the OS, after that every time I hover over any icon desktop is restarting, I tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop, reinstalled unity, reinstalled compiz, nothing fixed it, this is the error logs:

```
[ 1579.610892] compiz[4943]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f6718b14eb6 sp 00007ffdcb440830 error 4 in i965_dri
  .so[7f6718532000+82d000]
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with what Ubuntu version you were using and updated to what version?

Comment: This is caused by recent updates, you will find many questions on the site about it. Applies if you have older Intel graphics.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes you are right.. it is a duplicate, thanks,  switched to gnome! it's a new world here!